# convergence test for improper integral of a function, where some part of the integral range, the function is not defined?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

As f(x) is not defined for some part of the integral range, what do we say about the convergence of below integral?

$\int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If $x>1$, $x(1-x)<0$ and your integrand doesn't make sense. In fact, $x(1-x)>0 \iff x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I have found this in one of the real analysis textbooks, so I am asking. So we can't comment on its convergence right, as it is not defined in some part of the integral range.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing some absolute vsalue?

Comment: yeah, I am sure, that is what has been given in that textbook.